# NoReverseMatch at /wiki/CSS Reverse for 'edit_pagina' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<editPage>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, html, django

i have tried to put an edit button on the wiki page but it give me this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /wiki/CSS Reverse for 'edit_pagina' with no
> arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P[^/]+)$']

urls.py:

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page>", views.wiki_page, name="wiki_page"),
    path("create", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("edit/<str:editPage>", views.edit_page, name="edit_page")
]
```

views.py:

```
def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

def edit_page(request, editPage):
    content = util.get_entry(editPage)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "page_title": editPage,
        "content": content
    })
```

edit.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ page_title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'edit_page' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <h1>Edit Page</h1>
        <textarea name="edit-content" id="textarea-content">{{ content }}</textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save-edit" type="submit">save changes</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: Note that you would normally use `<slug:slug>` in the URL pattern, and use a slug e.g. `my-page-title` instead of the title (e.g. `My Page Title`).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide the needed argument for your url.

So you need to change:

`{% url 'edit_page' %}`

To:

`{% url 'edit_page' page_title %}`

Assuming that `page_title` will give you the relevant page you want to edit.

Comment: but need the page to edit like: edit/css or edit/python for example

Comment: The view uses `page_title` instead of `editPage` - `{"page_title": editPage, "content": content}` - so it should be `{% url 'edit_page' page_title %}`

Answer (score 1):

change your **edit.html** as:

```
<form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit_page' page_title %}" method="POST">
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `editPage` argument so that Django can reverse the URL:

```
{% url 'edit_page' page_title %}
```

In your case, I'm using `page_title` because you set `"page_title": editPage,` in your template context.